# Missing file field in Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using paperclip in nested attributes and I'm not sure what I'm missing. The view on the form is missing the file upload option.

**Form**

```
<%= form_with(model: news, local: true, html: { multipart: true } ) do |form| %>
   <%= form.fields_for :images do |img| %>
     <%= img.file_field :img, multiple: true %>
   <% end%>
<% end %>
```

**Models**

```
class News < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true
end

class Image < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :news

has_attached_file :img, :styles => { :show => "600x600>" }, size: { less_than: 2.megabytes }
  validates_attachment_content_type :img, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"]
end
```

**Controller**

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @news = News.new
    @news.images.build
  end

  def create
    @news = News.new(news_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @news.save
        format.html { redirect_to @news, notice: 'News was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @news }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @news.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  private
    def set_news
      @news = News.find(params[:id])
    end

    def news_params
      params.require(:news).permit(:title, :description, :category, images_attributes: [:id, :img, :news_id, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

If I change `:images` to `:image` in the form the field appears, but then gives an error on submission:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you need to explicitly pass a `record_object` to the `fields_for`

```
<%= form.fields_for :images, @news.images.build do |img| %>
  <%= img.file_field :img, multiple: true %>
<% end%>
```

Also in order to send multiple values for `img`, it should be an array in the permitted params. You should change the `news_params` to below

```
def news_params
  params.require(:news).permit(:title, :description, :category, images_attributes: [:id, :news_id, :_destroy, img: []])
end
```

Comment: Works! Odd, why in Rails 5 do you have to call the build method in the form rather then the controller under New?

Comment: @DollarChills I guess it has to do with `model: news` in `form_with`. Just to be curious try keeping the `fields_for` as it is before and change `<%= form_with(model: news, local: true, html: { multipart: true } ) do |form| %>` to `<%= form_with(model: @news, local: true, html: { multipart: true } ) do |form| %>`

Comment: That method works better. This lists all image when editing, whilst the other method does not. Wonder if there where changes to this nested attributes with rails 5?

Comment: Could be. There isn't any information on how to use `fields_for` with `form_with` I tried checking [*here*](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) but nothing.

Comment: I just defaulted to form_for and works fine. Rails 5 defaults to this new form_with which I was suspecting to work the same. Cheers once more.